# How can I add a git tag for a specific jenkins build?

Tags: git, jenkins, tagging

I am looking for a way to tag a git changeset from withing Jenkins. I enabled the Jenkins build tagging plugin which allow me to tag builds in jenkins but these are not git-tags, as this seems to me more like a way to rename build in jenkins.

I need a **manual git tagging option in Jenkins**, not an automatic one.

For automating tagging I am already using the Git Published post-build step, but that's another kind of tagging.

Comment: Git tags points to a specific commit. Jenkins job can build the same commit N times, so you can not tag a specific jenkins build with a git tag.

Comment: To be clear: I want to tag the git changeset, on demand, after the build was made, even if it was made two weeks ago. i want something very similar to the tag option in jenkins, the difference being that this would be a git tag that is pushed, not a jenkins only tag, which is more like a label.

Comment: Ok, this clears it up a bit. And it has to be done in Jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

> I need a manual git tagging option in Jenkins, not an automatic one.

use this line of code in your script:

```
git tag -a <tag> -m <message>
```

This will create ***`annotated`*** tag with the given message attached to the given tag.

> ***-a*** = annotated tag.
>   Annotated tags is a full blob which contains the same information as commit (author, email, date message etc).

Comment: I think you didn't understand it. I cannot know in advance which build I want to tag, I need to do this AFTER the build was made. This has to be something that is not part of the build process.

Answer (score 0):

The **Git Publisher** plugin for Jenkins might be worth a look:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It exactly what he said he doesn't want to do !!!. Please read the last part of the Question